# ¿Como hacer consultas preparadas con VB.NET y SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Tengo experiencia programando en Java y he tomado como proyecto personal aprender lenguajes .NET (VB.NET y C#).

En JAVA se utiliza lo siguiente para crear consultas preparadas MySQL y así evitar el SQL injection:

```java
 public void consultaPreparada() throws SQLException{
   conexion();
   String query="SELECT * FROM staff where first_name=(?) and password=md5(?)";
   ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
   ps.setString(1, "Mike");
   ps.setString(2, "contrasena");
   rs=ps.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
       System.out.println(rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));

   }
    cerrar();
 }
```

Quisiera saber como hacer las consultas preparadas pero en VB.NET y SQL Server. Hasta ahorita solo las se hacer así:

```vb
Public Sub agregar(ByVal CURP As String, ByVal nombre As String, ByVal apep As String,
                   ByVal apem As String, ByVal sexo As String, ByVal ocupacion As String)
    'Se abre la conexion'
    conectarBD()
    'Se genera el String de la Consulta
    Dim consulta As String = "INSERT INTO persona VALUES('" + CURP + "','" + nombre + "','" + apep + "','" + apem + "','" +
         sexo + "','" + ocupacion + "')"
    'Agregamos la sentencia SQL y la conexion
    cmd = New SqlCommand(consulta, conn)
    'Establecemos una variable auxiliar  para determinar si la consulta se ejecuta bien o no
    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    'compara si la consulta fue hecha bien si esta es mayor que 1
    If i > 0 Then
        'Si la consulta es correcta manda este mensaje
        MessageBox.Show("Persona Agregada con exito")
    Else
        'si la consulta es incorrecta manda el siguiente mensaje
        MessageBox.Show("Error al Agregar")
    End If
    'se Cierra la conexion
    cerrarConexion()

End Sub
```

Comment: Si provienes de Java, te sentirás muy cómo con la sintaxis de C#. Échale un vistazo al namespace System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Muchas gracias sstan por la observación, como muchas cosas que he leído mencionan a Visual Basic como parte de .NET Framework pues lo tome cómo tal, gracias por la  observación.

Comment: Francisco si creo que me adentrare a buscar más información acerca de SqlClient de C# la ventaja es que la sintaxis de muchas cosas de C# es similar a Java, gracias.

Comment: No confundas VBA (Visual Basic for Aplications) con Visual Basic (.NET)

Comment: Gracias @CarlosMuñoz por la aclaración, no viviré mas en ese error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas Evitar SQL Injection, usando SQLClient de esta manera:

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new 
    SqlConnection(Parametros.Config.GetCadenaConexionString()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cadena="";
                cadena = "select * from wan.VistaRptPresupuesto pp where 
                SUBSTRING(pp.CuentaCodigo,1,4) = @CuentaCodigo";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cadena, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CuentaCodigo", 
                Convert.ToString(Cuenta)));
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, hace varios días leyendo llegue a la propiedad Parameters de SqlCommand, de todas Formas Muchas Gracias por el aporte @Myk FLr.

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo encontré la forma de hacerlo, mediante la propiedad `Parameters` de `SqlCommand`.

A continuación dejo la solución:

**ConexionBD.vb**

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class ConexionBD
Public conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=bd;User ID=usuario;Password=password")
Public cmd As SqlCommand
Public dr As SqlDataReader
Public Function conectar() As SqlConnection
    Try
        conn.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Conectado")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try
    Return conn
End Function

Public Function cerrar() As SqlConnection
    conn.Close()
    Return conn
End Function

End Class
```

**ConsultaSQLSimple.vb**

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class ConsultaSQLSimple : Inherits ConexionBD

Public Function conSimple()
    Try
        conectar()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE staff_id=@idStaff", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idStaff", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters("@idStaff").Value = 1
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows Then

            dr.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(dr.GetSqlString(1) + " " + dr.GetSqlString(2))
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
    End Try
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Hola Ferny. Gracias por aportar tu respuesta. Para beneficio de otros lectores debo mencionar que 1- no es buena práctica usar una conexión global como lo haces (en cualquier lenguaje de programación es una práctica peligrosa) 2- Relacionado a lo anterior, no me parece conveniente usar herencia simplemente para poder acceder a algunos métodos comunes. 3- Es importante liberar los recursos como la conexión, el data reader cuando terminas de usarlos, y la mejor manera de hacerlo es por medio de bloques `Using`. 4- No es buena práctica tener un bloque `Catch` que simplemente ignora la excepción.