# Error al comparar dos fechas en PostgreSQL VB .NET

Tags: postgresql, vb.net

Para poner en contexto, estoy creando un exportador de datos de **PostgreSQL** a un fichero de Excel.

En caso de que haga una consulta, y me devuelva una respuesta, la escribo correctamente en el Excel y se guarda correctamente, pero el problema me aparece en la clausula `where` de una consulta que estoy haciendo, en la que intento comparar un campo de tipo `date` con la fecha actual del sistema.

```
Dim myConn As PgSqlConnection

pgConnectionString = "host=127.0.0.1;database=Prueba;user id=postgres;Password=*****;"
myConn = New PgSqlConnection(pgConnectionString)

Dim myCommand As DbCommandBase = myConn.CreateCommand()

Dim fechaHoy = System.DateTime.Today

Dim senSql = "select * from product_pricelist_version ppv where ppv.date_start <= " & fechaHoy

myCommand.CommandText = senSql

myConn.Open()
resultadoQueryTarifas = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Y me dice que mi campo `fechaHoy` es del tipo `integer`, por lo que me falla la consulta y no me devuelve nada. ¿Como podría hacer esta comparación?

> Primera excepción del tipo 'Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlException' en Devart.Data.dll
> el operador no existe: date <= integer

Comment: El error viene posiblemente porque las fechas en .net se almacenan realmente como un entero, y al concatenar la consulta lo que realmente le llega al motor de base de datos es un entero. La mejor solucion es usando una consulta parametrizada en lugar de concatenar el texto. [Aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/112656/15301) puedes ver un ejemplo

Comment: WOW, lo he puesto de la manera en la que se menciona en el enlace que me has proporcionado, y me ha funcionado. Lo de que la feche llegue como un entero no lo termino de entender del todo, pero me sirve con lo que me has pasado. Muchas gracias

Comment: Como se explica [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) _Internamente, todos los DateTime valores se representan como el número de tics (el número de intervalos de 100 nanosegundos) que han transcurrido desde las 12:00:00 medianoche, 1 de enero de 0001_  Por eso lo que le llega al concatenar es un entero con los tics. El error seria diferente si hubieras hecho `Convert,ToString(fechahoy)`por ejemplo

Comment: Anotado, algo nuevo que aprendo. Muchas gracias por compartir tu conocimiento. Voy a dejar la pregunta por si algún usuario se encuentra con un problema parecido. Un saludo